# Метки (label) в Python

Tags: python

Можно узнать, есть ли метки в Python. Например при каком то условии переходи на метку 1. И если есть то как это делается?

Comment: вы имеете в виду прогресс в обучении?

Comment: Нет goto, нет меток.

Answer (score 1):

[Таки есть в Питоне библиотека goto:](https://github.com/snoack/python-goto)

```
from goto import with_goto
i = 0
result = []
label .start
if i == 10:
   goto .end
result.append(i)
i += 1
goto .start
label .end
```

Comment: Python 2.7:`NameError: name 'label' is not defined`. Python 3.7:
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'goto'`

Comment: pip install goto

Comment: Не ставится. Пробовал и для питон 2, и для python 3.7.

Comment: Тогда модуль скачиваете по ссылке и кладете в папку с программой. Обратите внимание, что вы можете скачать архив с расширением zip. Его нужно распаковать и взять файл goto.py и положить в папку с программой. Например вы создали файл myfirstprogram.py, тогда файл goto.py должен находится там же где и ваш файл myfirstprogram.py (в той же папке).

Comment: по ссылке написано, что надо использовать pip install goto-statement

Comment: @Эникейщик кто же спорит, но для этого надо прочитать инструкцию.

Comment: @Эникейщик Вот эта команда `pip install goto-statement` не ставит:`ImportError: cannot import name with_goto`

Comment: @becouse Я читал инструкцию —  не помогло.

Comment: @VictorsaysReinstateMonica не знаю, у меня сработало

Comment: @Эникейщик У меня мак.

Comment: @VictorsaysReinstateMonica тоже в некотором роде мак - айфон.

Comment: @Эникейщик Pythonista ?

Comment: @VictorsaysReinstateMonica Pyto. Раздавали недавно бесплатно, ухватил :)

Comment: @VictorsaysReinstateMonica Тогда модуль скачиваете по ссылке и кладете в папку с программой. Обратите внимание, что вы можете скачать архив с расширением zip. Его нужно распаковать и взять файл goto.py и положить в папку с программой. Например вы создали файл myfirstprogram.py, тогда файл goto.py должен находится там же где и ваш файл myfirstprogram.py (в той же папке)

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
def func_1(*args, **kwargs):
    # что-то делаем
    return 'какой-то результат 1'

def func_2(*args, **kwargs):
    # что-то делаем
    return 'какой-то результат 2'

a = 1

if a == 1:
    rez = func_1()
elif a == 2:
    rez = func_2()
else:
    rez = 'Пусто'  # ничего не делаем

print(rez)
```

Comment: Это не метки...